# Creating a filter in javascript to filter results through url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I feel like I am really close to figuring this out. Iv tried so many different ways.

- I want to create two `selects` one for `writing_type` and the other for `sort_by` in the `agreement` model, to filter the results. I think I need a different code in JS file for `index.html` and possibly edit in my controller.
- I found a piece of a solution to my problem, but i couldnt figure out the rest of what i need to make this work.

**What i think i need to do:** change the model variable to accept `params[:writing_type]` and `:sort_by`?

[image]

Index.html

```html
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/scribe_requests" method="get">
  <input type='submit' value="go">

  <select id="querySelct" name="writing_type">
    <option value=":all" label="Writing Type">Writing Type</option>
    <option value="College Applications" label="College Applications">College Applications</option>
    <option value="College Essays" label="College Essays">College Essays</option>
    <option value="Business Papers" label="Business Papers">Business Papers</option>
    <option value="Resumes" label="Resumes">Resumes</option>
    <option value="High-School Essays" label="High-School Essays">High-School Essays</option>
    <option value="Scholarship Essays" label="Scholarship Essays">Scholarship Essays</option> 
    <option value="Language Translation" label="Language Translation">Language Translation</option>   
  </select>

  <select id="landingSelect" name= "sort_by">
    <option value="created_at desc" label="Sort By">Sort By</option>
    <option value="created_at desc" label="Due Date(closer)">Due Date(closer)</option>
    <option value="created_at asc" label="Due Date(further)">Due Date(further)</option>
  </select>

</form>
```

controller:

```rails
def index

      @agreements = Agreement.where("accepted = ?", false).where("due_date >= ?", DateTime.now).where("writing_type = ?", params[:writing_type]).order(params[:sort_by]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)

 end
```

Here is partial being called in index.html.erb

```html
</div class="agreements-list">
  <%= render 'agreements/lists', agreements: @agreements %>
     </div>
```

The model agreements has columns that i want to sort it by and `writing_types` that i want to filter with.

So the plan is to use the url and based off the url the list will change it uses `&writing_type=1` for example to include at the end of the URL.

How can i add the script URL to the main URL at the top and have it refresh on its own? i can add ajax later!! Unless you have the ajax answer with it? thank you so much this is very important to me! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feels like you are doing something straightforward in quite a hard way. You should be able to achive what you want without all the JS by doing it in a form as follows:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/agreements" method="get">
  <input type='submit' value="go">

  <select id="querySelct" name="writing_type">
    <option value="0" label="Writing Type">Writing Type</option>
    <option value="1" label="College Applications">College Applications</option>
    <option value="2" label="College Essays">College Essays</option>
    <option value="3" label="Business Papers">Business Papers</option>
    <option value="4" label="Resumes">Resumes</option>
    <option value="5" label="High-School Essays">High-School Essays</option>
    <option value="6" label="Scholarship Essays">Scholarship Essays</option> 
    <option value="6" label="Language Translation">Language Translation</option>   
  </select>

  <select id="landingSelect" name= "sort_by">
    <option value="0" label="Sort By">Sort By</option>
    <option value="1" label="Due Date(closer)">Due Date(closer)</option>
    <option value="2" label="Due Date(further)">Due Date(further)</option>
  </select>

</form>
```

By putting it in a form, with names against the selects, it should submit to the form path (I have guessed it is a get request to `/agreements` which will route to your index action in the controller), with the parameters populated based on what option is selected

In your index action you should then be able to get the parameters by `params[:writing_type]` and `params[:sort_by]`

Update:

To handle all writing types, do it in your index controller differently e.g.

```
if params[:writing_type] == "all" #or whatever option represents all
  @agreements = Agreement.all
else
  @agreements = Agreement.where(writing_type: params[:writing_type])
end
```

Comment: Okay so i got it working having to change the numbers to the actual writing_type and changing the controller.  however how can i make that default value for `writing_type`  be all of the writing_types?  I tried making an array in the select option for the first choice but im not getting any results that way.

Comment: Just added an update to show how you can handle that in the controller

Comment: I changed and that seems to work however on the loading of the page at the beginning before filtering i get no results until i click the go button. how can i get it to auto load `all`? I added `selected` on the option for all but it seems like the form has to go through first. is there a way to display before the form submit? or maybe formsubmit on load?

Comment: On the first load of the page no `params[:writing_type]` will not be present so you can change your if statement to `if params[:writing_type] == "all" || params[:writing_type].nil?` to default to all

Comment: yea  haha i just added this `if params[:writing_type] == nil
  params[:writing_type] = "all"
end`